# Using multiple font types

Tags: fonts

I wish to use the font tgpagella without it being used throughout the entire document. How do I import this font into my document without causing it to be used by default?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look into `tgpagella.sty`, you find there (after some complex code setting the scaling which you probably do not need) the line `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{qpl}`.  This means that tgpagella font is encoded by fontname scheme as `qpl`.  Then the solution is to call this family directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
This is typeset in default font.  {\fontfamily{qpl}\selectfont This
  is typeset in tgpagella.}  And default font again.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might add how one is supposed to find the correct string.

Comment: What do you mean by "the correct string"?

Comment: I think @egreg meant `qpl`

Comment: OK. I understand, thanks for updating the answer.

Comment: @Josh See this post by Alan Munn. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document