# Inserting a different font type in the same document

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I am using `\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}` (Garamond font) for the main font in my document, but I don't like how the produced `\mathcal{L}` looks like. I need that L to look like in default font. I looked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47546/using-multiple-font-types), and tried loading either pxfonts or txfonts, since that has 'normal' `\mathcal{L}`, but no luck :|

So is it posible to combine those two?

Since I'm writing something that contains Lie derivatives I made the following swich:

```
\newcommand{\Lie}{ \mathcal{L}}
```

so I don't have to write the mathcal part over and over. But I'd like it to look 'ordinary', not extra swirly :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a standard font setup and don't load many other math font packages, the simplest way is to say

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\xcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\Lie}{\xcal{L}}

\begin{document}
$\Lie$
\end{document}
```

If you want the standard calligraphic shape for all letters in `\mathcal`, just change the two lines with `\xcal` in them into

```
\let\mathcal\relax % "undefine" \mathcal
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\Lie}{\mathcal{L}}
```

However, if one of the above results in a "Too many math alphabets" error, there is another, albeit less efficient, strategy:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\xcal}[1]{\text{\usefont{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}#1}}
\newcommand{\Lie}{\xcal{L}}
```